# Nexus : How to get libraries from Sonatype Nexus using Bash or Batch or Python?

Tags: python, bash, batch-file, nexus, sonatype

I have some libraries  (***.dll, *.lib**) that I need to store in a remote **Sonatype Nexus repository**, and then use them in my solution which is a collection of "**C# .Net**" and "**C/C++**" projects.

To get the libraries, I need to write :

1. a **Bash script** to execute it in **Cygwin** (this would be the best solution)
2. Or, a batch script
3. Or, a Python script.

For information : I'm not using Maven at all.

Could you please give me some hints and some samples by scripting **to get the libraries from Nexus**?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In the Repositories tab in the Nexus UI there should be a clickable link in the Repository path. So find the repo with your files and browse through until you have the full path in the Nexus repo then use tool (wget/curl/httpie) or write something to download it.

Comment: This the right answer. Thanks a lot. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personnaly used wget because it has more options for downloading.

Here it is the way I did :

```
wget http://NEXUS/PATH/TO/MyLibrary.dll -P .\local_output_directory
```